# Access form data in form builder to add custom attribute

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I'm creating form witch has collection type and collection element has field with data transformer witch is ID to Entity converter:

```
$builder->add(
        $builder->create('template', 'text', array(
            'label' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'template-selector',
            )
        ))->addModelTransformer($transformer)
    );
```

This is needed because I want to turn this field to Select2 (javascript lib) ajax powered element.

Problem is that I need to populate Select2 with data, to do this I have have only one reasonable (for performance) option pass data from form builder as attribute (let say data-value) but form builder has any data unless I create element in EventListener but then I cannot add model transformer.

How could I achieve such functionality? Without any additional queries or ajax calls?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to do this in twig template:

```
{% if item.get('value').template %}
    {% set templ_id = item.get('value').template.getId %}
    {% set templ_text = item.get('value').template.getTitle %}

    {{ form_row(item.template, {'attr': {'data-value' : '{id:' ~ templ_id ~ ', text:"' ~ templ_text ~ '"}'}}) }}
{% else %}
    {{ form_row(item.template) }}
{% endif %}
```

Where item is form collection element